# ng test | An unhandled exception occurred: Error in config file! Error: Cannot find module 'karma-remap-istanbul'

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am getting the below error when I run ng test - what am I doing wrong/missing?

**An unhandled exception occurred: Error in config file!
Error: Cannot find module 'karma-remap-istanbul'**

my karma.conf.js file is below.

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/platform-ui'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That issue was solved, by removing `node_modules` and reinstalling them (you might not need to do this step), and then running:

```
npm i karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter
```

Comment: this never worked. already have karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter too. weird problem for me

Answer (score 0):

`karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter` is deprecated in Angular >= 11, you have to update your package.json with the new `karma-coverage` then change `require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),` in karma.conf.js with `require('karma-coverage'),`.